# Changes that apply to my new div class aren't showing up in my website

Tags: html, css

When I change the container to be the class button1, I see the area around the button becoming orange, when I change that class to be send-message-button, it does not become green but rather white. I can add style to send-message-button if I do it within the html file but I am not sure as to why I can't do it using my styles.css file. Additionally, when I type class=", button1 shows up but not send-message-button.

```css
.empty-text {
  color: #777;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.sent-message {
  background-color: #15c6f7;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  width: 25%;
  float: right;
}

.received-message {
  background-color: rgb(201, 206, 208);
  color: rgb(90, 124, 92);
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}

.send-message-button {
  background-color: #2ce168;
  border-color: #2ce168;
  color: white
}

.button1 {
  background-color: #e1862c;
  border-color: #e1862c;
  color: white
}

.card-infoDisplay {
  background-color: #e1862c;
  border-color: #e1862c;
}

.real-name {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.user-major {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.titleDiv {
  height: 1rem;
  background-color: rgba(500, 0, 0, .1);
  border: solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  border-width: 1px 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 .5em 1.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), inset 0 .125em .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.sectionDiv {
  height: 0.25rem;
  background-color: rgba(500, 0, 0, .1);
  border: solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  border-width: 1px 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 .5em 1.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), inset 0 .125em .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.searchDiv {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  gap: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="send-message-button">
  <button class="btn btn-light" type="submit">Send Message</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Cleared your cache?

Comment: clear the cache, clear the cache... ;-)

Comment: Is clearing the cache just the same as reloading the webpage?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want it to look like?

```css
.empty-text {
  color: #777;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.sent-message {
  background-color: #15c6f7;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  width: 25%;
  float: right;
}

.received-message {
  background-color: rgb(201, 206, 208);
  color: rgb(90, 124, 92);
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}

.send-message-button {
  color: white
}

.btn.btn-light {
  background-color: #2ce168;
  border-color: #2ce168;
}

.button1 {
  background-color: #e1862c;
  border-color: #e1862c;
  color: white
}

.card-infoDisplay {
  background-color: #e1862c;
  border-color: #e1862c;
}

.real-name {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.user-major {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.titleDiv {
  height: 1rem;
  background-color: rgba(500, 0, 0, .1);
  border: solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  border-width: 1px 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 .5em 1.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), inset 0 .125em .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.sectionDiv {
  height: 0.25rem;
  background-color: rgba(500, 0, 0, .1);
  border: solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  border-width: 1px 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 .5em 1.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), inset 0 .125em .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.searchDiv {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  gap: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="send-message-button">
  <button class="btn btn-light" type="submit">Send Message</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't have 50 'Reputation' to ask you via a comment on you question post, apologies.